# Next.js with firebase: SSR and SSO

Tags: reactjs, firebase, seo, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently working on a website that has its data stored in firestore. The website needs good SEO, so I chose to use Next.js. However, when a use clicks a link, it will take 1-2 seconds for the server to get the data from firebase. This is a bad user experience, because the user has no way of knowing that the page is actually loading.

How would you send an "App shell" (Page with no data), before getting the data from `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: Development mode can be a bit slow with loading, but do you get that same delay when running the Next.js app in production mode (`next build && next start`)?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I get the same delay in production.

Comment: I can't think of a solution to the issue using `getServerSideProps`. The alternatives would be to: 1) investigate why the delay getting the data from Firebase is happening and try to reduce it; 2) use `getStaticProps` instead and pre-render the pages at build-time (may not be an option depending on your requirements).